# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file after opening file

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
import os

csv_out = 'femaleconsolidated.csv'

csv_list = [r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\filemerger\Female\outputA.csv',
            r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\filemerger\Female\outputB.csv',
            r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\filemerger\Female\outputC.csv',
            r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\filemerger\Female\outputD.csv',
            r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\filemerger\Female\outputE.csv',
            r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\filemerger\Female\outputother.csv']
print(csv_list)
csv_merge = open(csv_out, 'w')
for file in csv_list:
    csv_in = open(file)
    for line in csv_in:
        csv_merge.write(line)
    csv_in.close()
    csv_merge.close()
print('Verify consolidated CSV file : ' + csv_out)
```

The code is to merge CSVs. 
Surely `open(file)` should open the file but I get this:

```
    csv_merge.write(line)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you need to use the full path of the file and not just the file name?  You walk the whole path so I assume the file isn't in the working directory but in some sub folder.

Comment: I have updated the question to include all the file names and the new case.

Comment: `csv_merge.close()` this should sit outside of the `for`loop - since you are still writing to `csv_merge`in next iteration

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat add that as an answer below, I think that should be it.

Comment: @AniMenon some answers are here already :D

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat Yours is good. Post it so we can upvote it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`csv_merge.close()` this should sit outside of the `for` loop - since you are still writing to `csv_merge` in next iteration :

```
for file in csv_list:
    csv_in = open(file)
    for line in csv_in:
        csv_merge.write(line)
    csv_in.close()
csv_merge.close()
```

Comment: @PythonIsBae use the green tick to mark this as the solution if this solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to writer line by line you should try this. You dont need to worry for closing the file when using this package - csv

```
import csv

destination = open(csv_out , 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(destination)
...
for line in csv_in:
    csvwriter.writerow(line)
```

If you just want to merge all files in a single one, there are more efficient ways to do it, not line by line. You can check this one 
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-combine-multiple-csv-files-with-8-lines-of-code-265183e0854/

Comment: Thank you, I have done something similar and have updated the question. Please see edits.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

dfs = glob.glob('path/*.csv') #path to all of your csv

result = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(df) for df in dfs], ignore_index=True)

result.to_csv('path/femaleconsolidated.csv', ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your **for** statement should be inside the *with* block:

```
with open(csv_out, 'w') as csv_merge:
    for file in csv_list:
        csv_in = open(file)
        for line in csv_in:
            csv_merge.write(line)
        csv_in.close()
        csv_merge.close()
    print('Verify consolidated CSV file : ' + csv_out)
```